# Flutter web: "webdev could not run for this project"

Tags: dart, web-development-server, flutter-web

When I run webdev server in my flutter web project I see this error:

> webdev could not run for this project.
>
> This version of webdev does not support the `build_daemon` protocol used by your version of `build_runner`.
>
> A newer version of webdev is available which supports your version of the `build_daemon`. Please update.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kznar.png)

dev_dependencies:
build_runner: ^1.4.0
build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
pedantic: ^1.0.0

Comment: For better answers, please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by your version of `build_daemon` not being compatible with your version of `build_runner`.

Please check your `pubspec.yaml` file and examine the versions of these two dependencies.

You may need to update the versions 
(see [latest build_runner version](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner/versions) and [latest build_daemon version](https://pub.dev/packages/build_daemon/versions). Or perhaps you are encountering [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33651#issuecomment-497972047) which can be fixed by downgrading your `build_daemon` version.

If you update your question with your dependency versions it will be easier to help.

To update webdev you must reactivate it:

```
$ pub global activate webdev
# or
$ flutter pub global activate webdev
```

Comment: how I can change my version of webdev?                                                                                  dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0

Comment: I've updated my answer with the steps to update webdev

Comment: thank you very much, when I try this command I find the same mistake.
but I found this command to update sdk dart with webdev choco upgrade dart-sdk but makes me this message Access to the path 'C: \ ProgramData \ chocolatey \ lib \ dart-sdk \ .chocolateyPending' is refused.

Answer (score 0):

You have juste to add `build_daemon: ^1.0.0` in `dev_dependencies:` of your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Let us know if it fix your error.

Comment: thank you , but no it doesn't fixed i get this message : This version of webdev does not support the `build_daemon` protocol used by your version of `build_runner`.
A newer version of webdev is available which supports your version of the `build_daemon`. Please update.